# VBA Get File Count using FileSystemObject

Tags: arrays, vba, filesystemobject

I'm writing a function at the moment that tries to get the file paths of all the files that have been uploaded to a SharePoint directory in the last week. I then want to copy the files across to my local PC.

My thinking goes like this

**Function 1** - gets a list of a folders

- **Function2** takes each folder and searches the file paths for each 
  file created in the last week and returns an array of file paths

**Function 3** - Copies across the files based on the array of file paths

I'm having trouble with the array. I want to specify the array size in advance based on the number of files in each folder. My code and the error is below

Can anyone see the problem

```
Public Function get_remoteTables(strPath As String)

Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFiles As file
Dim filedetails() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

' Grab all the files in the subfolders
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    'print folder path
    Debug.Print (objSubFolder.Path)
    Set objFiles = objFSO.GetFolder(objSubFolder.Path).Files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            FileCount = 0
        Else
            FileCount = objFiles.Count
        End If
    get_Filenames (objSubFolder.Path)
Next objSubFolder

End Function 

Sub test()

Call get_remoteTables("C:\temp\ ")

End Sub
```

> Compile Error Method or Data member not found: FileCount = objFiles.Count

Answer (score 1):

Although i wasnt able to understand why i was getting the error, I found a function [online](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3159-excel-count-files-in-folder-directory.html) that seems to do what i need. I adapted the function and added the function to the code above

```
Public Function CountFiles(xPath As String)

Dim xCount As Long
Dim xFile As String

xPath = "C:\temp\HelloWorld\"
xFile = Dir(xPath)
Do While xFile <> ""
    xCount = xCount + 1
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
CountFiles = xCount

End Function
```